# Group records by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table named "invoices". I would like to sum the amount and grouped it by companies and date

```
+------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+
| company_id | company          | date        | amount    |
+------------+--------------------------------+-----------+
|    1       | chevrolet        | 2017-11-18  |   100     |
|    1       | chevrolet        | 2017-11-18  |   -70     |
|    1       | chevrolet        | 2017-11-25  |   50      |
|    2       | mercedes         | 2017-04-01  |   30      |
|    2       | mercedes         | 2017-04-01  |   -30     |
|    2       | mercedes         | 2017-09-01  |   50      |
|    3       | toyota           | 2017-05-12  |   60      |
+------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+
```

The desired result is:

```
+------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+
| company_id | model_name       | date        | amount    |
+------------+--------------------------------+-----------+
|    1       | chevrolet        | 2017-11-18  |   30      |
|    1       | chevrolet        | 2017-11-25  |   50      |
|    2       | mercedes         | 2017-04-01  |   0       |
|    2       | mercedes         | 2017-09-01  |   50      |
|    3       | toyota           | 2017-05-12  |   60      |
+------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do `GROUP BY`, and use `SUM()`.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the spec in english there, it just needs translating to SQL:

```
select company_id, model_name, date, sum(amount) as amount
from invoices
group by company_id, model_name, date
```

In MySQL you can (depending on how it's configured) get away without doing the GROUP BY line, and you might see SQLs like this on your travels through the world of MySQL:

```
select company_id, model_name, date, sum(amount) as amount
from invoices
```

MySQL is implicitly inserting the group by for you.. Personally I'd always recommend to put it in explicitly, as few other DBs do an "auto group by" and sticking to standard SQL makes your SQL knowledge more portable. You might also find strong proponents of the "group by should always be implicit" argument which, I acknowledge, has its merits :)

Answer (score 0):

Together

```
SELECT 
SUM (amount) 
FROM <table-name> 
GROUP BY company, date;
```

For grouping by company

```
SELECT 
SUM (amount) 
FROM <table-name> 
GROUP BY company;
```

For grouping by date

```
SELECT 
SUM (amount) 
FROM <table-name> 
GROUP BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
SELECT company_id, model_name, date , SUM(amount) AS amount 
             FROM invoices GROUP BY company, date;
```

See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) for more about `GROUP BY` clause and examples.